# How to script a REPLACE statement in SQL 2012?

Tags: sql, replace

First of all let me say that I'm an absolute rookie in SQL and scripting, so please talk to me as to a little child. ;)

I have a huge number of databases that contain tables in which I have to replace user information in specific columns.

Old: Instance A; Database B,C,D,...; Table E; column F,G,H,...; value 1,2,3,...

New: Instance A; Database B,C,D,...; Table E; column F,G,H,...; value 1a,2a,3a,...

Is there anyone out here who can give me a little bit of hope and help?
This job is on the scale of 3000 databases, so it is a must for me to script it.

I appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE TableE
SET ColumnF =  ColumnF + 'a',
    ColumnG =  ColumnG + 'a'
WHERE Clause...
```

Comment: Not sure I explained it well enough.
I'll have to replace the value with a complete different one. Unfortunately, it's not just to add an "a". :)
But thank you for your response.

Comment: In set section you can define columns new value. You can append to old value (ColumnF = ColumnF + 'a') or set new value (ColumnF = @Parameter). Where is your new value?

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this is what you are looking for.

```
UPDATE b
  SET a.col1 = b.col1
     ,a.col2 = b.col2
  FROM myTableA AS a
  INNER JOIN myTableB AS b
    ON a.key1 = b.key1
```

Here is some more examples: [How can I do an UPDATE statement with JOIN in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql)

There is also a JOIN example under "Updating Data Based on Data From Other Tables" here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this query for the bulk update script.

```
select  'IF  EXISTS(SELECT * FROM SYS.OBJECTS WHERE  OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(N'''+
'['+d.name+'].['+SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)+'].[ '+t.name+']'''+ '))'+
'BEGIN update ['+d.name+'].['+SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)+'].['+t.name+'] SET '+c.name+ ' = '+c.name+ '+ ''a'''+ ' END'
FROM sys.databases d,sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
WHERE c.name in('F','G','H')
        and t.name='table_E';
```